# Serialize Object with PersistentCollection To JSON

Tags: json, symfony, serialization

I want to serialize entity object in my Symfony2 application to JSON object (I have to pass it to ajax function and use it in my javascripts).

Everything works fine but I have in my entity object addresses which are PersistentCollection object. Then if I serialize them in normal way field "adresses" has got empty Object. I figured out that I can set "LimitedRecursiveGetSetMethodNormalizer" to "1" and then PersistentCollection is being serialized. The problem is that I've got this object serialized, not array with my addresses so I can't use them in my javascript because they are not there...

```
\Cloud\ApplicationBundle\Resources\LimitedRecursiveGetSetMethodNormalizer::$limit = 1;
$businessJson = $this->get('serializer')->serialize($business, 'json');
```

Variable $business is of course Entity Object. I hope that my question is clear.
I have to add that I know that i can convert PersistentCollection object to Array and then serialize it to Json but this way i would have to pass my entity and adresses in seperate variables. I would prefer to do it one variable.

Thanks for any help !